# LetsEncrypt SSL installation on LightSail AWS Ubuntu 18.04 Server Hosting and domain from Godaddy

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, amazon-lightsail

Followed this link steps to install SSL on AWS LightSail Ubuntu Server: https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04.

But https://example.com not loading.

Is there any configuration missed?
And it is necessary to add a TXT record in the DNS setting after the LetsEncrypt Certificate installation?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is or what is it that you do not understand.

Comment: @Yogeshwar Installing LetsEncrypt SSL Certificate on the AWS-LightSail Ubuntu Server hosted website. But after successful installation my website not loading with https://.... Also added TXT record in DNS settings of the domain. followed above menstioned link to install SSL.

Comment: @Yogeshwar hope you got my point. Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used **Lightsail DNS Zone** for DNS Management instead of Godaddy for using LetsEncrypt SSL installation on LightSail.After moving DNS Management from Godaddy to Lightsail try LetsEncrypt SSL installation.strong text